# user gets logged out if wifi changes flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have application, where users are get logged out if they changes wifi. How to avoid that ? How to make sure they are persistence logged into application.

FYI: I don't have to worry about adding new user.

I am using flask and login_manager.

My library as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, \
logout_user, login_required
from flask import request, render_template, flash, redirect, \
url_for, Blueprint, g, jsonify
```

Initializing flask app as follows

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'Validpointer'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
```

This how I am allowing users to login

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


@auth.before_request
def get_current_user():
    g.user = current_user

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)
@auth.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('auth.contact_form'))

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()


        if user.password == password:
                    login_user(user)
                    return redirect(url_for('auth.contact_form'))
        else:
             flash(
                'Invalid username or password. Please try again.',
                'danger')
            return render_template('base.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear [Kppatel Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1972924/kppatel-patel),

Please try to modify initializing flask app as follows:

`login_manager.session_protection = "basic"`

Please [Refer this](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#session-protection) article for more info. And let me know if further clarification needed.